# Auto-update a csv based with edited grid in streamlit-aggrid

Tags: python, ag-grid, streamlit

I am new to `Streamlit` and `streamlit-aggrid` so I am trying to figure this simple case out.

#### # Goal:

1. Load a table from a `csv` as `df`
2. Display it in `streamlit`
3. Edit some cells using `streamlit-aggrid`
4. Overwrite the `df` with the edits **without any button click**
5. Save it back to the `csv`
6. Continue with step 1

#### # Issue:

I was able to do this process and the first edit works like a charm, but it seems I need an additional trigger to reload the dataframe, which is where the code is not working as intended. It does update the dataframe, but takes a page refresh or editing a cell 2 times (basically an additional trigger) to save the update to the csv.

My question is, is there a way to make such edits on the fly, directly to the csv, while loading the updated csv back to the agGrid object? And to do this without using a button click as a trigger to refresh / update / save the data?

#### # My code:

Here is my sample working code, which has the issue at hand.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from st_aggrid import AgGrid

#df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3], "col2": [4, 5, 6]})  # Original csv
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

grid_options = {
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "headerName": "col1",
            "field": "col1",
            "editable": True,
        },
        {
            "headerName": "col2",
            "field": "col2",
            "editable": False,
        },
    ],
}

grid_return = AgGrid(df, grid_options)
df = grid_return["data"]

df.to_csv('sample.csv', index=False) #Overwrite sample.csv

## CHECK IF SAMPLE CSV IS UPDATED ##
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
st.write(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add a key to the AgGrid().

```
grid_return = AgGrid(df, grid_options, key='df')
```

Comment: awesome, it works like a charm. could you elaborate ho this works? Thanks!